# Getting wiener filter coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to find two coefficients (w1,w2) for a wiener predictor filter of the signal
`x(n)=0.65x(n-1)-0.7x(n-2)+v(n)`
where:
`x(-1)=x(-2)=0` and `v(n) = white noise`
I have already gotten points to evaluate like this:
`for i=1:2000
    vn(i) = randn(1,1)-0.5; %create the noise;
    x(i) = 0;
end
for i=3:2000
    x(i) = 0.65*x(i-1)-0.7*x(i-2)+vn(i); %first 2000 points of the signal
end`

Now I'm a little lost, I don't know how to get this coefficients to create a wiener predictor of type `y(n) = w1*x(n-1) + w2*x(n-2)`

Comment: Look up Weiner-Hopf equations for a linear predictor. It's straightforward once you have the right equation for the cross-correlation terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a Matlab function that calculate the coefficients matrix from your function:

```
function x = xt(t)

for i=1:t

    vn(i) = randn(1,1)-0.5; %create the noise;
    x(i) = 0;

end

for i=3:2000

    x(i) = 0.65*x(i-1)-0.7*x(i-2)+vn(i); %first 2000 points of the signal

end
```

in an archive `xt.m`

Then in other command line put (or `.m` file)

`r_tau = xcorr(xt(1999));`

and calculate your `matrix_R` with `r_tau;` `r(0)` `r(1)`  `r(-1)` and `r(-2)`

`matrix_R = [r_tau(2000), r_tau(2001); r_tau(1999),r_tau(2000)];`

and your `matrix_r` from `[r(-1) r(-2)]`

`matrix_r = [r_tau(1999); r_tau(1998)];`

Finally multiply the inverse or `matrix_R` with `matrix_r` to obtain your weight's vector

```
w = (inv(matrix_R))*matrix_r;
```

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I have edited your answer to include proper formatting for code. In the future please use either `\` code goes here \`` or four spaces before each line of code in order to put it in a code environment.